# Wrong looping/Reading C++

Tags: c++

I am just learning C++. I wrote a program that shows the repeated letters in a string (I also have to count how many times it the letter gets repeated). The thing is when I run my code to get the repeated letters from the sentence. It runs okay for some but not some. For example: "hi there" runs good returning h and e, but something like "people are nice" returns peeeeee.The repeated letter should be shown only once. Point the problem out to me please. I assumed it had to do with the looping but can't figure it out exactly.

```
void repeatWord(string sentence)
{
    for(int i=0; i<sentence.length(); i++)
        for(int j=i+1; j<sentence.length(); j++)
            if((!isspace(sentence[i]))&&(sentence[i] == sentence[j])){
                cout<<sentence[i]<<endl;
            }
    return;
}
```

Comment: This is a very inefficient way to do what you want to do. Use a hash if you care about efficiency.

Comment: @RSinghS A hash is over the top for single letters.

Comment: @RSinghS the guy's just learning... gotta walk before you can run :)

Comment: There is nothing in your code which limits the letters to only be  printed once -- not sure I understand why you expect that.  Also, are you looking for consecutive repeated letters or just letters which are repeated anywhere in the string?

Comment: Well, `e` appears in `people are nice` 4 times, so it should be printed 3+2+1 = 6 times, as you can see. If you want to print each letter that appears more than once **only once**, then you need to use a hash map of some sort (`int hash[256] = {0}` would be the simplest one).

Comment: You have found 6 = 3 + 2 + 1 'e's which is consistent with the double looping. Indeed if you purposely put in a typo (such that you now have 5 'e's in your sentence) you would get peeeeeeeeee (i.e. 4+3+2+1 'e's).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is your inner loop.  It displays the letter once every time it's encountered.  Also, you do not break out of the loop after seeing a duplicate, so you get an exponential mess.

A better way is to just record how many times you've seen a letter.  That requires just one loop and an array:

```
int count[256] = {0};
for( int i = 0; i < sentence.length(); i++ ) {
    char c = sentence[i];
    if( isalpha(c) && count[c]++ == 1 ) cout << c;
}
```

Instead of the array, you can use `std::set`.  That would be more appropriate if you were handling Unicode.  However, we're just dealing with a `char` here, which is 8 bits on almost every architecture you're likely to be practising on.

---

A little bonus of doing it this way is that you compute the letter frequencies.  You can output these as follows:

```
for( int c = 0; c < 256; c++ ) {
    if( count[c] ) cout << (char)c << " : " << count[c] << endl;
}
```

If you want to output case-insensitive counts, one way to do it is like this:

```
for( int c = 'a'; c <= 'z'; c++ ) {
    int total = count[c] + count[toupper(c)];
    if( total ) cout << (char)c << " : " << total << endl;
}
```

Comment: Paddy, this kind of does what I was intending to do. The letters that appear more than once should be displayed only once. If I wanted to print out a column by side showing how many times that letter appeared in the string is this something I have to do with matrix so I can just write another method that will display how many times the letters appeared. For example. e 6 on one line and p 2. on the second line? Thanks for tip!

Comment: @AdeqHero Yes, I suspected you might want the letter counts so that's why I used this approach (instead of boolean array).  All you need to do is go through the array afterwards and output any non-zero entries.  I have edited my answer to illustrate.

Answer (score 1):

Getting rid of repeating letters is easy: just insert into a `<set>` or delete the letters after you see them. Inserting into a set is more efficient however:

```
set<char> letters;
for(int i=0; i<sentence.length(); i++)
    for(int j=i+1; j<sentence.length(); j++)
        if((!isspace(sentence[i]))&&(sentence[i] == sentence[j])){
            letters.insert(sentence(i));
        }
for(auto &i : letters)
    cout << i << endl;
```